# How to open a DBF file with compatible locking in ARC32 from the command line?

Tags: dbf, advantage-database-server, file-locking

I have an application that was written in Harbour (Clipper compiler).

The application is using compatible locking and has the table open.

The error message I get when I try to open the table with ARC32 from command line is:

```
Browse table error 7028:Invalid open mode
```

I used this command line:

```
ARC32.exe test.dbf
```

I'm using a remote ADS server (not ALS).

How can I tell ARC32 to open the file in compatible locking mode?

My ads.ini file:

```
[SETTINGS]
ADS_SERVER_TYPE=2
DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 0
LockingMode=compatible
DBFTableType=cdx
[ARCAFS02]
LAN_IP=10.20.1.20
LAN_PORT=6262
```

Comment: I don't think ARC32 can take any command line switches, but you can look at the source code. When you install ARC32 you can optionally install the source code as well.

Answer (score 1):

ARC32 (as of version 11.10) doesn't take any command line switches (aside from the object [table / dictionary] name(s) to open.

You can read that in the source code:

1. `ParamStr()` is called in a loop at main.pas:3029 to open tables / dictionaries
2. `ParamStr()` is also called to get it's own executable name in winutils.pas
3. A `GetCmdLineOption` utility function is defined at `sutils.pas` that does command line parsing (also using `ParamStr()`) , but is never used in the rest of the ARC32 source code.

Regarding your locking problem, the answer depends on several things:

- Do you use compatible or proprietary locking?
- Do you use ADS (the remote server) or ALS (the local server)
- What is the other application that has the table open?
- What is the actual error message.

You should clearify your question.

Comment: I use compatible locking
I ise  ADS the remote server
Other applicasion is weittel in harbour (clipper compiler)
My errror is 
"Browse table error 7028:Invalid open mode"

Comment: I have edited the question for you. Did you try to put a 'ads.ini' file (with locking set to compatible) into your working directory? Or if this doesn't work into the ARC32 directory?

Comment: How can i put myfolter g:\test in ads.ini?

[SETTINGS]
ADS_SERVER_TYPE=2
DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 0
LockingMode=compatible
DBFTableType=cdx

[ARCAFS02]
LAN_IP=10.20.1.20
LAN_PORT=6262

Comment: You can use a database alias in the ads.ini file: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?ade_database_aliases_and_the_ads_ini_file.htm

Comment: But since your original question is about calling ARC32 from command line that probably won't help, you have to modify the ads.ini file that ARC32 is reading (search your C:\ drive for "ads.ini", I think that it is stored in a VirtualStore folder, since ARC32 does not carry a manifest and tries to store it in C:\WINDOWS or something).